# Python virtualenv: After activate, pip is still the gobal one

Tags: python, pip, vagrant, virtualenv

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 in a vagrant guest machine.

I installed `virtualenv` throught apt (`apt install virtualenv`), and then I created a python3 virtual environment like this:

```
virtualenv -p $(which python3) .venv
```

This is the output I got:

```
created virtual environment CPython3.8.10.final.0-64 in 161ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/srv/apps/bali/bali-backoffice/app/.venv, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, pkg_resources=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/vagrant/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1.debian.1)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
```

Now, if I activate this virtualenv, the `python` command refers to the one in the `.venv` folder, but the `pip` command, however, refers to the OS one, under `/usr/bin`, as this output states:

```
vagrant@v-host:/home/vagrant/app$ source .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) vagrant@v-host:/home/vagrant/app$ which python
/home/vagrant/app/.venv/bin/python
(.venv) vagrant@v-host:/home/vagrant/app$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip
(.venv) vagrant@v-host:/home/vagrant/app$
```

What's causing this? How can I fix this?

**Update #1**
Forgot to mention, but the `pip` executable is in the `bin` folder of the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how to solve the error, but I'm not entirely sure yet as to why this solution works.

The `.venv` folder was inside a synced folder. Although the `python` executable was being created via symlink to `/usr/bin/python3`, the `pip` executable was being downloaded and included in the `.venv/bin` folder.
I checked the permissions assigned to files and directories inside the `Vagrantfile`, and this was what I had:

```
config.vm.synced_folder _conf['synced_folder'],
    _conf['document_root'], :create => "true", :mount_options => ['dmode=755', 'fmode=644'],
    SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate: false
```

Changing the `fmode` value to 755 solved the problem, but I am not sure why that happens...